# Как сверстать такие карточки?

Tags: html, css

Как сверстать такие карточки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня вот что получается, но как сделать это как на картинке? У меня не получается сделать такую тень, как на картинке.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  width: 180px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) inset;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cards {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.card {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  border: .1em solid #e0e0e0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) inset;
}

.card:before,
.card:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 70%;
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 55%;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transform: skew(-15deg) rotate(-6deg);
}

.card:after {
  left: auto;
  right: 10px;
  transform: skew(15deg) rotate(6deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Красота, можно ещё `grid-template` добавить, чтобы ровненько всё было на всех устройствах.

Comment: Почему это? Я лично тестировал практически на всех устройствах.

Comment: Ахахах так прям там же есть примеры с гридом )))) Если всё настроить корректно и указывать не в пикселях, а в соотношении, то на всех устройствах будет смотреться одинаково. Лично проверено.